# Installing VMware

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I want to install VMware in my Ubuntu 14.04. While executing:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

I'm getting a notification:

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release i386 (20140417)'in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter
```

Answer (score 1):

That notification means you need to insert your Ubuntu installation CD to install new packages.

It seems you need to learn a bit more about [package management](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/package-management.html) and the [sources.list](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SourcesList) file. You should edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to [change current repositories and add additional ones](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/configuration.html).

This could be an example:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
```

That being said, you can take a look at [Ubuntu Wiki page about VMware](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware) as it provides information about that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this commands:

mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom

rm -rf /tmp/*

tar -C /tmp -xzvf /media/cdrom/VMwareTools*.tar.gz

/tmp/vmware-tools-distrib/vmware-install.pl -d

## rm -rf /tmp/*

restart